# php sql data/ table works with smaller sample txt file but not full 50mb txt file?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a php/sql program that functions correctly with the SQL.txt file below.. however sql.txt is only a few sets of data for test purposes .. the real txt file is same format but 50mb.  when i use the small test my code works and outputs the table.. but when i try the 50 mb file it does not  compute and just brings up a blank  screen on my localhost/sql.php.  does anyone have suggestions for getting a program to work with 50mb the same it works with a 1mb txt?

below is my smaller sql.txt file (very small compared to actual 50mb file, but same format) and php file thank you for any guidance.

sql.txt file

```
<pub>
<ID>0</ID>
<title>Regression Time Warping for Similarity Measure of Sequence</title>
<year>2004</year>
<booktitle>CIT</booktitle>
<pages>826-830</pages>
<authors>
    <author>Hansheng Lei</author>
    <author>Venu Govindaraju</author>
</authors>
</pub>
<pub>
<ID>1</ID>
<title>A Computational Model for Face Location Based on Cognitive Principles</title>
<year>1992</year>
<booktitle>AAAI</booktitle>
<pages>350-355</pages>
<authors>
    <author>Venu Govindaraju</author>
    <author>Sargur N. Srihari</author>
    <author>David B. Sher</author>
</authors>
</pub>
```

php file for inserting data

```
<?php



$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db1');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
printf("connect failed\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();    
}


error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n<datalist>";
$content = $header."\n".file_get_contents("sql.txt")."\n</datalist>";
$ob = simplexml_load_string($content);
$json = json_encode($ob);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$alldata = $array["pub"];




foreach ($alldata as $key => $value) { //access all data in loop
$id = $value["ID"];
$title = $value["title"];
$year = $value["year"];
$booktitle = $value["booktitle"];
$pages = $value["pages"];
$authors = implode(",", $value["authors"]["author"]);


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pubs VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss',
                   $value["ID"],
                   $value["title"],
                   $value["year"],
                   $value["booktitle"],
                   $value["pages"], implode(",", $value["authors"]["author"]));
$stmt->execute();
printf("%d row insrt\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>title</th>
<th>year</th>
<th>booktitle</th>
<th>pages</th>
<th>authors</th>
</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $value['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $value['title'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $value['year'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $value['booktitle'] .  "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $value['pages'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $value['authors'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";



}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: After how long does it present the blank screen? Somewhere around 30 seconds I presume?

Comment: you are reading the whole 50mb in to memory, reading it in chunks would be a better idea

Comment: You might be maxing out your memory reading that much data too. Doing this with XML parsing may not be the way to go...

Comment: the blank screen shows immediately. got any links on reading this into chunks or maybe a better idea for me?

Comment: Test with 25mb, 10mb etc, to see where it fails. Then see if it is perhaps bad data record, invalid characters, or corrupt file. If you move the records around, will it still fail at the same size? This will at least tell you if you are running into memory/size issues.

Comment: Change error reporting to E_ALL. Always check the log first; it's your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

Blank page from php is usually out of memory. 30 secs of execution time will end your script and warn you on the screen if you have the needed values.

Read the error logs please, you will find it.
If you modified the post_max to put in 50mb file is cool but it need to handle it anyway.

I suggest you to put these few lines into top of your php to ensure the code is not prematural ended.

`ini_set('memory_limit', '0');`
`ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');`
`ini_set('max_post_size', '0');`
`ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

If you put the 50mb file and some of it has been processed to the database, your problem is NOT the post_size, is the memory, time or both at time!
Also, adding `error_reporting('E_ALL')` will log any type of error... remember, read the log.